# Display binary data as image into the table in JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, image

I would like to attached a binary format image in the table. The data is dynamic which depends on the selected item. Currently, I have implemented this one.

```
var notes = _jobMgr.GetNotes(transportLegId)
                .Select(a => new
                {
                    date = a.N_Date.ToString(),
                    note = a.N_Note,
                    image = a.Images.FirstOrDefault().I_Image
                });

            return Json(notes);
```

However, if there's no image for that note, it will have an error. May I ask how also to get the image without affecting the return data if there's no image.

In the JQuery side, I have implemented this to display the data.

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + btoa(data[i].image);
                var noteRow = "<tr><td>" + data[i].date + "</td><td>" + data[i].note + "</td><td>" + img + "</td></tr>";
                $('#note-tbody').append(noteRow);
            }
```

I wonder why the image is not displaying but this text `[object HTMLImageElement]`

Thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked two questions (I think), so I'll see if I can hit them both:

---

> May I ask how also to get the image without affecting the return data if there's no image.

Do you mean errors in the C#? You could use a [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
image = a.Images?.FirstOrDefault()?.I_Image
```

This sets `image = null` if `Images` or `FirstOrDefault()` are `null`, rather than throwing an exception.

You could account for this in the JavaScript with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), where we use the image if we have one, but otherwise we'll just use an empty string. This would also solve your second issue, because you'd be creating the element as a `string` instead of an `object`.

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    var img = data[i].image ? `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${btoa(data[i].image)}">` : "";
    var noteRow = "<tr><td>" + data[i].date + "</td><td>" + data[i].note + "</td><td>" + img + "</td></tr>";
    $('#note-tbody').append(noteRow);
}
```

---

> I wonder why the image is not displaying but this text `[object HTMLImageElement]`

Your `img` variable is not a `string`, but rather an `object`, so you can't concatenate it in this fashion.

In the future, if you wanted to get the HTML string from an element object, you could use [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).

Answer (score 1):

I think it works.

```
 var noteRow = "<tr><td>" + data[i].date + "</td><td>" + data[i].note + "</td><td>" <img src="+img.src+" /></td></tr>";
```